# How do I reindex a collection using Mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

Mongoid provides a few rake tasks, one of which creates the indexes for all collections in the database:

rake db:create_indexes

But correct me if I'm wrong, isn't creating indexes different than actually indexing all of the items?  How can I go about reindexing my documents?  This would be necessary if I added an index to a new collection in Rails but already have 10,000 items in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid db:create_indexes only call the `ensure_index` on Mongodb.

On Mongodb when you ensure a new index, it will create the index and also re-index the existent docs on the collection. You have to be carful with that, because Mongodb is going to lock the DB, until the index is fully functional. 
If you have 10k items, it should lock for a few minutes only, maybe less. But if you go over million docs, than you must do it in other ways.

Comment: This does not reindex a specific collection.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to manually remove the old index and create the new ones specified in your model.

`Model.remove_indexes
Model.create_indexes`